# MySQL connection problems

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble connecting to my MySQL database on a machine other than localhost.

On my localhost, I can connect to my MySQL database using the Workbench and execute commands, modify everything and such and such, but if I try to connect to it via *another* machine, using a matching IP and port number (I've looked and checked! Even used netstat to see what's being listened to!) no go. Even on the same network, I type in its IP (`192.168.1.120`), but it refuses to connect at all, even just typing in the IP in the browser with the port number fails to connect, not even getting that file that says the packets are out of order!

I have tried port-forwarding, flushing/restarting/reloading configuration, re-checking my firewall and anti-virus, but all to no avail.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your database or your server?

Answer (score 2):

From a MySQL connection you *can* make, give this query. You'll need a privileged connection.

```
      select host, user from mysql.user
```

Look for a row mentioning the hostname and username with which you are trying to connect.  The `user` table mentions each user and the host or hosts from which it is allowed to connect.

You may have to issue commands like these to give yourself a user entry capable of remote access:

```
  CREATE USER   'alan'  @  '%' IDENTIFIED BY 'REDACTED_PASSWORD';
  GRANT EXECUTE, PROCESS, SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, SHOW VIEW, ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, DROP, EVENT, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, TRIGGER, UPDATE, CREATE USER, FILE, LOCK TABLES, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, SHUTDOWN, SUPER  ON *.* TO 'alan' @ '%' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If this is your problem, no worries. You're not the first person to have it.